# C# HttpWebRequest for datetimepicker

Tags: c#, php, mysql, datagridview

I am working on an C# application which would use the remote MySQL database located in my website hosted on a Linux server with PHP & MySQL support.

I tried to get the selected from and to date in datagridview using datetimepicker.

enter image description here

my form contain 2 datetimepicker(dateTimePicker1 and dateTimePicker2) when i click the button. it need to search from date and to date in database table and show it in a datagridview.

i connect my datagridview in database table. but my problem is that when i select some date and click the button the datagridview get empty.

populate the datagridview using php coding:

**PHP FILE : (data.php)**

```
<?php
$servername = "***.**.***.***";    
$username = "root";
$password = "pasword";
$dbname = "databas";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT calldate,time_interval,campaign,agent FROM aster");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print(json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
?>
```

**c# coding for populate datagridview:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HTTPDGV
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
 class User
        {
            [JsonProperty("calldate")]
            public string calldate { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("time_interval")]
            public string time_interval { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("campaign")]
            public string campaign { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("agent")]
            public string agent { get; set; }
        }
 public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://***.**.***.***/data.php");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream);
            String json = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
            List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = users;    
          }
       }
     }
   }
```

it work well.

but here is my my problem

**PHP FILE : (time.php)**

```
<?php 

$date1 = $_POST['calldate'];
$date2 = $_POST['calldate'];

$servername = "***.**.***.***";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT calldate,time_interval,campaign,agent FROM aster_agent_performance WHERE calldate BETWEEN'$date1'AND'$date2'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print(json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
?>
```

**c# coding for datetimepicker:**

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var date2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            HttpWebRequest myRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://***.**.***.***/time.php");
            myRequest.Method = "GET";
            using (WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
                    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("calldate=" + date1 + "AND" + date2 + "");
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    String json = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
                    string date = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = date;
                }
            }
}
```

when i click search button the datagridview get empty . please check my coding where i make mistake.Please suggest any online links or tutorials.

My Question is here: http://www.voidasks.com/c_httpwebrequest_for_datetimepicker#answers

Does anybody have any idea about this coding or can anybody tell me if I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: `$date1` and `$date2` the same `$_POST` input? Are you sure that's right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   var date2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://***.**.***.***/time.php");
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fromdate= " + date1 + " & todate=" + date2);
   request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
   Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
   stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
   String json = reader.ReadToEnd();
   List<Users> user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(json);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = user;
```